# An equality of maxima

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-functions

Let $0<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_N<1$ be $N$ points of $[0,1]$. I was reading something in which it says that the following two expressions are *clearly* equal:

$$\max_{1\leq i\leq N}\max\left(\left|\frac{i}{N}-x_i\right|,\left|\frac{i-1}{N}-x_i\right|\right)=\frac{1}{2N}+\max_{1\leq i\leq N}\left|x_i-\frac{2i-1}{2N}\right|.$$

I can prove it tediously by going through all cases of "What if this is the maximal element...", but I don't see why it is clear?

Also, what is really going on here? Somehow we manage to reduce the $2N$ elements in the maximum on the left hand side to just $N$ elements on the right hand side. There must be a special structure to this problem that lets us do this.

Comment: Shouldn't the R.H.S be $\frac{1}{2N}+\text{max}_{1\le i \le N} |x_i-\frac{2i-1}{2N}|$? If I set $x_i \to 0$ for all $i$ and $N \to \infty$, the L.H.S gets closer to $1$ as the R.H.S gets closer to $2$.

Comment: @GyuminRoh yes, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking at $$\max_{1\leq i\leq N}\max\left(\left|\frac{i}{N}-x_i\right|,\left|\frac{i-1}{N}-x_i\right|\right)$$
We look at $$\max_{1\leq i\leq N}\max\left(\left|\frac{i}{N}-x_i\right|-\frac{1}{2N},\left|\frac{i-1}{N}-x_i\right|-\frac{1}{2N}\right)$$

Case 1. If $x_i \ge \frac{2i-1}{2N}$

In this case, we note that $|\frac{i-1}{N}-x_i| \ge |\frac{i}{N}-x_i|$.

Therefore, we have $\max \left(\left|\frac{i}{N}-x_i\right|-\frac{1}{2N},\left|\frac{i-1}{N}-x_i\right|-\frac{1}{2N}\right)=|\frac{i-1}{N}-x_i|-\frac{1}{2N}=|x_i-\frac{2i-1}{2N}|$

Case 2. If $x_i \le \frac{2i-1}{2N}$

This case is handled similarly.

We note that $|\frac{i}{N}-x_i| \ge |\frac{i-1}{N}-x_i|$.

Therefore, we have $\max \left(\left|\frac{i}{N}-x_i\right|-\frac{1}{2N},\left|\frac{i-1}{N}-x_i\right|-\frac{1}{2N}\right)=|\frac{i}{N}-x_i|-\frac{1}{2N}=|x_i-\frac{2i-1}{2N}|$

Now the result follows! We are done. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks! I think this approach touches on an important point: If we shift the max of the left hand side, then it ends up concerning distances to the average of $i/N$ and $(i-1)/N$ (which is exactly $(2i-1)/N$).

Comment: I was going to suggest  considering  the  3 cases $x_i<(i-1)/N, x_i\in [(i-1)/N, i/N, x_i>i/N$.  Except there is already a good answer. I didn't think it  so obvious. .... What is "clearly" true is subjective.

Comment: @HowDoIMath Yep, that was my motivation for this solution.